# Walking over strings to guess a name from an email based on dictionary of names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, pattern-matching, email-validation

Let's say I have a dictionary of names (a huge CSV file).  I want to guess a name from an email that has no obvious parsable points (., -, _). I want to do something like this:

```
  dict = ["sam", "joe", "john", "parker", "jane", "smith", "doe"]
  word = "johnsmith"
  x = 0
  y = word.length-1
  name_array = []
  for i in x..y
     match_me = word[x..i]
     dict.each do |name|
       if match_me == name
         name_array << name
       end
     end
  end   

  name_array
  # => ["john"]
```

**Not bad, but I want "John Smith" or ["john", "smith"]**

In other words, I recursively loop through the word (i.e., unparsed email string, "johndoe@gmail.com") until I find a match within the dictionary.    **I know: this is incredibly inefficient.**  If there's a much easier way of doing this, I'm all ears!

If there's not better way of doing it, then show me how to fix the example above, for it suffers from two major flaws: (1) how do I set the length of the loop (see problem of finding "i" below), and (2) how do I increment "x" in the example above so that I can cycle through all possible character combinations given an arbitrary string?

Problem of finding the length of the loop, "i":

```
  for an arbitrary word, how can we derive "i" given the pattern below?

  for a (i = 1)
  a

  for ab (i = 3)
  a
  ab
  b

  for abc (i = 6)
  a
  ab
  abc
  b
  bc
  c

  for abcd (i = 10)
  a
  ab
  abc
  abcd
  b
  bc
  bcd
  c
  cd
  d

  for abcde (i = 15)
  a
  ab
  abc
  abcd
  abcde
  b
  bc
  bcd
  bcde
  c
  cd
  cde
  d
  de
  e
```

Comment: Further research shows that "i" can be derived using a sequence of triangular numbers: a(n) = C(n+1,2) = n(n+1)/2 = 0+1+2+...+n.  http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+3%2C+6%2C+10%2C+15&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dare suggest a brute force solution that is not very elegant but still useful in case

- you have a large number of items (building a regexp can be a pain)
- the string to analyse is not limited to two components
- you want to get all splittings of a string
- you want only complete analyses of a string, that span from ^ to $.

Because of my poor English, I could not figure out a long personal name that can be split in more than one way, so let's analyse a phrase:

```
word = "godisnowhere"
```

The dictionary:

```
@dict = [ "god", "is", "now", "here", "nowhere", "no", "where" ]

@lengths = @dict.collect {|w| w.length }.uniq.sort
```

The array `@lengths` adds a slight optimization to the algorithm, we will use it to prune subwords of lengths that don't exist in the dictionary without actually performing dictionary lookup. The array is sorted, this is another optimization.

The main part of the solution is a recursive function that finds the initial subword in a given word and restarts for the tail subword.

```
def find_head_substring(word)

  # boundary condition:
  # remaining subword is shorter than the shortest word in @dict
  return []  if word.length < @lengths[0]

  splittings = []

  @lengths.each do |len|
    break  if len > word.length

    head = word[0,len]

    if @dict.include?(head)
      tail = word[len..-1]

      if tail.length == 0
        splittings << head
      else
        tails = find_head_substring(tail)
        unless tails.empty?
          tails.collect!{|tail| "#{head} #{tail}" }
          splittings.concat tails
        end
      end
    end
  end

  return splittings
end
```

Now see how it works

```
find_head_substring(word)
=>["god is no where", "god is now here", "god is nowhere"]
```

I have not tested it extensively, so I apologize in advance :)

Comment: I like where this is headed, but this approach has difficulty with "johnjsmith", when "j" is not in the dictionary.  The @the Tin Man's approach seems to ignore the "j" and find other matches within the string.

Comment: Although... it looks like I can just add all of the individual letters of the alphabet to @dict.  In which case, your method returns "john j smith".  Pretty good!

Answer (score 5):

```
r = /^(#{Regexp.union(dict)})(#{Regexp.union(dict)})$/
word.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "johnsmith" 1:"john" 2:"smith">
```

The regex might take some time to build, but it's blazing fast.

Comment: I like it but I think you want ^$ boundaries

Comment: What are the ^$ boundaries for?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the hits of matches in your dictionary:

```
dict.select{ |r| word[/#{r}/] }
=> ["john", "smith"]
```

You run a risk of too many confusing subhits, so you might want to sort your dictionary so longer names are first:

```
dict.sort_by{ |w| -w.size }.select{ |r| word[/#{r}/] }
=> ["smith", "john"]
```

You will still encounter situations where a longer name has a shorter substring following it and get multiple hits so you'll need to figure out a way to weed those out. You could have an array of first names, and another of last names, and take the first returned result of scanning for each, but given the diversity of first and last names, that doesn't guarantee 100% accuracy, and will still gather some bad results.

This sort of problem has no real good solution without further hints to the code about the person's name. Perhaps scanning the body of the message for salutation or valediction sections will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with i, but isn't it as simple as:

```
dict.each do |first|
    dict.each do |last|
        puts first,last if first+last == word
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This one bags all occurrences, not necessarily exactly two:

```
pattern = Regexp.union(dict)
matches = []
while match = word.match(pattern)
  matches << match.to_s # Or just leave off to_s to keep the match itself
  word = match.post_match
end
matches
```